How to change the port in API after `npm run build`
client/
  scriptWhichMakesApiCall/
         await axios.get("http://localhost:${REACT_PORT}/api/product-category");

Doing "npm run build". REACT_PORT value is baked into build.

server/
      express which dynamically assigns itself some PORT.

What modificatoins can i make to my codebase, so that my build react app makes call to the exact port my express app is listening to?
I have hard coded the PORT number in react app.
Build it.
Also hard coded the PORT number in express. This doesn't seem robust.

To anyone stuck on this problem.
just use a relative URL, like '/api/product-category'.
That way it will automatically use the same hostname and port that the page was served from. So in this way no PORT is used while building the react app.

Make sure to set your express server port yourself. You can do so by adding the below code to your express server entry file:
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; /*set 3000 to your desired port number*/

Then can use the port in your react by adding it to your axios call.
await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/product-category");


Hey, thanks for the reply.
The thing is, I am doing 'npm run build' which take PORT and is hardcoded. And my express app is dynamically allocating itself PORT. This leads to mismatch in the URL. However, this problem is solved by 'relative url'

Nice to see you found a way around it. You are welcome

You can use the env file
npm install dotenv --save
Next, add the following line to your app.
require('dotenv').config()
Then create a .env file at the root directory of your application and add the variables to it.


// .env 
PORT=3000





client/
  scriptWhichMakesApiCall/
         await axios.get("http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/api/product-category");



